# How to set the ReadPreference in mongodb with java api

Tags: mongodb

the  `Mongoclient.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.primary())` in java api  is deprecated
 the document shows

> Set the default read preference with either **MongoClientURI** or
>   **MongoClientOptions**

but  I find  `MongoClientOptions` doesn't  have  `setReadPreference`  method  .but in  `MongoOptions`  .but  it looks strange  ,`MongoClientOptions` doesn't  extends `MongoOptions`  .
firstly  I wanted to know  what is the relationship about the two options ,did they have the same effection ?
secondly , tell  me how  to set ReadPreference   in java api , you'd better show me your code  `(MongoClientURI or MongoClientOptions)`.thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MongoOptions` is deprecated. You can't set the `readPreference` directly. You have to use `Builder` to set the `readPreference`.

Something like

```
MongoClientOptions clientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder().readPreference(ReadPreference.PRIMARY).build();
```

Comment: You can only include a MongoClientOptions at the time of constructing your MongoClient, e.g., new MongoClient("localhost:27017", clientOptions)